# Return feedback to user for a void a web service method call in a try-catch block?

Tags: java, web-services, exception, try-catch, return-value

I'm using a web service from a third party, which I don't have control over and what it does is, it modifies data in a system but returns void, so I execute the call to it using a try/catch block.

Now my question is: should I always assume that if no exception is thrown (caught) it has been excuted successfully?

The reason why I ask is because I want to give the user some feedback about the status of their action, whether it has been successful or not and given the fact that the web service method returns void, I'm thinking of just placing, for instance, some message like "your action is correctly executed" after the method call in the try-block.

Is that a good way to go about it or are there more better ways? FYI Java is the programming language Iam using.

Comment: Don't assume anything without confirmation or verification. If confirmation is not there in terms of success code returned, then try to verify the changes by reloading/getting the data.

Comment: I'd like to hope that any competent web-service would throw an exception/ failure result if it couldn't.. and "unit" return on normal control flow, means it succeeded. _This is a reasonable expectation of how it (and all software in general) should behave -- but ring the provider or establish this experimentally, to be sure._